# Qi Charger is Cycling

Tags: wireless-charging

I have a Samsung S5 with a [WOWTOU receiver](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JXFQ480).  It was working fine, but after a week or so, it now cycles, even when the S5's battery is not full.  I've tried multiple different brands of Qi transmitters, and they all do the same thing.  It does get hot at times, but there is no correlation with the temperature and the cycling.  Different transmitters seem to cause different rates of cycling, but I haven't done a real experiment to see what those are.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have any sort of case on the phone?

Comment: No case. Just the standard back cover.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how you've placed it. On some Qi pads you can even hear the difference...try moving the phone around while it's charging...

you can read [this](http://www.reddit.com/r/Nexus5/comments/2co7ed/be_careful_with_your_qi_chargingheat_issues/) post I made about the heat wasted during charging based on the inductive permeance the Qi pad "sees"

Comment: I switched out the Qi receiver from the WOWTOU to a [CHOETECH](http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00DDTZN4S), which seems to have stopped the cycling.  I will try the 2A charger to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I feel like Qi is half baked...wish it weren't